# Get value from Dictionary<String, Any>

Tags: ios7, dictionary, swift

I declared a `Dictionary<String, Any>` which has some Strings, Arrays and ints as values.
When I try to get back a value based on `String` key, I'm not able to cast it to `Array`,
even if that value identified by key is a real `Array`.

```
 let lColorValues = lTabBarDictionary[TabBarKey.tabBarColor] as Array;
```

p.s. `TabBarKey.tabBarColor` is a string

Apple's Swift Programming Book offers an example with an `Array` which store different kinds of objects, and they use `as` to downcast objects, which seems to work fine for `Array` but not for `Dictionary`.

Did I missed something ? How to get values for such Dictionary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the type the `Array` holds, for example:

```
class TabBarKey {
    class var tabBarColor : String {
        return "key"
    }
}

let arr = ["1", "2", "3"]

var lTabBarDictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>()

lTabBarDictionary[TabBarKey.tabBarColor] = arr

let val = lTabBarDictionary[TabBarKey.tabBarColor] as Array<String>
```

in the last line, I am using `Array<String>` instead of `Array`. You should do the same thing, using of course the proper generic type that the array holds.

Tested that code in playground and it prints the expected array.

Comment: what a stupid thing I did :)) Yes of course it must be Array<sometype> and not Array. Thanks

Comment: it's not stupid... new language, new way to do things, so it's easy and normal to overlook obvious things :)